# 3dsmax crashes when exporting

Tags: 3dsmax, collada, export

I'm trying to export a (.max) file to openCOLLADA (.dae). Whenever I do this, 3dsmax crashes and produces this error:

> An error has occurred and the application will now close. 
>       No scene changes have occurred since your last save.

3dsmax then crashes but the COLLADA file is still produced. Whenever I try opening this COLLADA file in other software though, it comes up with a bad mesh data error. This is leading me to think that it wasn't exported correctly out of 3dsmax. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporters are often very finicky. Try exporting nothing but a basic cube mesh. If that works, you know the issue is something within your mesh.

Unfortunately, this part is hard to give a definitive answer on. Basically you have to go over your mesh and ensure there's no *weird* parts that could cause the exporter to crash. This could be disconnected vertices, duplicated vertices, too many vertices, strange windings on vertices, strange normals between vertices and the list goes on. Essentially, you need to make sure you follow good practices when creating the mesh.

If you can't export the basic cube mesh either, there's an issue with your exporter and you should update it.

Finally, your last alternative is to start from scratch. Follow good practices to reduce errors. Try exporting the model or running STL check frequently during creating to make sure you're not propagating errors further.

Comment: Agreed, also run an STL check modifier on the mesh parts, it will point out flaws in the mesh.

Comment: Yea I'm able to export other files, its only this one that seems to produce the error. I ran the STL check and it identified 894747 errors. It doesn't show what layers the errors are in or even where the errors are. That's a ridiculous amount of errors though. Any advice on where to go from here?

Comment: @odoc I've updated my answer with a final alternative. It may sound like a lot of work, but it'll likely be faster/better than trying to track down and resolve all those errors. Also, if you try to keep the vertex counts low, it's likely you'll have fewer errors and they'll be easier to track down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It would be realistically impossible to start from scratch since I didn't orignially create the file (or else I would). Doing some more research online, I tried making a snapshot of each layer, and that worked in exporting perfectly. The only thing is, <i>some</i> objects lose their textures when I do this. Do you know much about snapshots? Do objects lose their textures when exporting snapshots? Cheers, help is much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, whether I make a snapshot or not, objects are losing their textures. There must be a simple solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @odoc Sorry, I've never even used 3DSMax. Sounds like you have a new issue if you've solved the export issue. Might be worth opening a new question for your new issue.